# asp:Menu not working in IE8, but working fine in firefox

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

i have a asp menu control which is controlled by sitemap data source. To make menu's look css friednly, i have used cssfriendlyadapters.browser in App_Browser folder. 
The menu works fine in firefox, but is not working in IE 8. please help.

below is the css file im using for menu.

```
    .navMenu
{
    width: 100%;
}

.navMenu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    display: block;
}

.navMenu ul ul
{
    display: none;
    left: 0%;
    top: 100%;
}

.navMenu ul ul ul
{
    left: 101%;
    top: 0px;
}

.navMenu li
{
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navMenu li li
{
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: none;
}

.navMenu a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;   
    width: 100%;
    float:left; clear:left; 
}

.navMenu a, .navMenu span
{
    display: block;        
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

/* Menu LAF Customizations */
.navMenu
{
    height: 21px;
    background: #F6F2E7;
}

.navMenu .AspNet-Menu
{
    background: #fff;
}

.navMenu li
{
    margin: 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #E1D5B0;
}

.navMenu li:hover
{
    background: #E1D5B0;
    border-color: #D8C797;
}

.navMenu li li
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;/* Setting 1px here creates a bug in IE, menu disappears */
    margin-left: -1px;
    background: #F6F2E7;    
    border-top-style: none; /* to offset above IE bug */
}

.navMenu li li:first-child
{
    border-top-style: solid; /* to offset above IE bug */
}

.navMenu a, .navMenu a:visited, .navMenu a:hover
{
    color: #000;
}

.navMenu li li.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren span 
{
    background:url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 97% center;
}
```

please help.